# Npm Sequelize Install

Tags: javascript, npm, sequelize.js

I am having some trouble with the Sequelize instalation. Here's what I've got:
[image: Problema]

Comment: "Program Files" is typically protected from non-elevated code making changes. Also, not finding a package.json looks like there is no node project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with sequelize...
You are trying to install sequelize in the C:\Program Files\nodejs folder and don't have any rights to do so.

If you are new to NodeJS: Try to init a new project in a different folder running `npm init` and then starting over there.